# Serverless azure-node.js template unable to find functions : Error : "No job functions found" (VS-code)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using serverless framework 
(https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/guide/quick-start/)

to create node.js based azure functions. I followed the procedure as stated in the quick start guide but facing the following issue while running it locally with npm start :

**No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.)**

Though the azure function service is up locally but it doesn't seem to find my functions.

What maybe missing here ? I am running this on VS code.

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through the steps on the documentation on serverless that you had referenced and everything is working for me. You'd definitely want to make sure that you run `sls offline` prior to `npm start` so that `function.json` file for each of the `hello` and `goodbye` functions get generated.